# Flow JS Union types and callbacks

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a flow curiosity regarding union types and callbacks, where it seems logically to me that the error cannot happen given the circumstances. I'm wondering if I'm having a brainfart, if flow just doesn't pick up such things, or it's something else

I've boiled the usecase down to it's core with the following [Try Flow Link](https://flow.org/try/#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), but I'll add it below for posterity. The case is when I have a function that takes in a union type as well as a callback that takes in the same union type.

If I have a separate function that restricts the type to just *one* of the types in the union, flow still complains that the callback could have *either*. It seems to me that, technically, Flow should have enough information statically to understand this can't happen, but again, maybe I'm brainfarting.

```
type A = {
  id: number,
  aOnly: boolean,
} 

type B = {
  id: number,
  bOnly: boolean
}

type AorB = A | B;

/**
  Main fn that takes in union type, as well as a callback that accepts
  the union type
 */
function main(ab: AorB, callback: (AorB) => boolean): void {
  callback(ab);
}


/**
  ONLY allows type A, therefore the callback should only be receiving type A
  in this scenario, yet flow thinks it could have either type
 */
function processA(a: A): void {
  main(a, (a) => {
    /* Cannot get `a.aOnly` because property `aOnly` is missing in `B` */
    return a.aOnly;
  });
}

/**
  Running the following gets:
  Cannot get `a.aOnly` because property `aOnly` is missing in `B`
 */
processA({
  id: 123,
  aOnly: true
});
```

What exactly is happening here? Is there a solution to this that doesn't involve adding in conditionals or disjoint unions?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

`main` accepts a callback which is typed `(AorB) => boolean`. You cannot pass a callback that doesn't accept an argument of type `AorB`, so it means it has to handle `A` case and `B` case. The fact that you pass a type `A` as `ab` doesn't change that, as Flow can't know that `ab` and the `callback` are linked.

For example, what if your `main` function was actually doing this?

```
function main(ab: AorB, callback: (AorB) => boolean): void {
  const callbackArg =  ab.id % 2 == 0 ? {id : ab.id, bOnly : true} :  {id : ab.id, aOnly : true}
  callback(ab);
}
```

It has the same signature, but calling it the way you would want to call it would fail as sometimes we pass a `B` to the callback.

#### Solution

There is a simple solution if you use a [generic type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/):

```
function main<T: A | B>(ab: T, callback: T => boolean): void {
  callback(ab);
}
```

[Try Flow Link](https://flow.org/try/#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)

This does exactly what you want : it accept `A` or `B` but the argument of the callback has to have the same type as `ab`.